# What technique did apple use to demo code in xcode on WWDC 2011 ?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4, wwdc

There are lots of WWDC 2011 video in apple's developer website. And in the video, there are some demo about coding in xcode.

The magic thing is: In these demo, the speakers didn't type the sample code one by one. They just press some keys in xcode, then the codes existed in xcode.

I think it's a good way to do the demo, so I want know what technique did apple use. I've do some research on the demo, it is not a simple "cmd+z" or "cmd+shift+z" method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an app called Demo Monkey. Apple actually provides it as a [sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/legacy/mac/library/samplecode/DemoMonkey/Introduction/Intro.html).

From the description:

> The example is a document-based application which serves as a "typing assistant". Each document contains a collection of text snippets which you can insert in turn into another application using a service. When creating a document, you can import text snippets also using a service.

Comment: Are there any shortcuts to go to the next snippet? Or do I have to change what to paste next time manually by selecting the next step in the app window?

Comment: It looks the link to the sample code project is broken. Any idea where is the app ?

Comment: @TsuneoYoshioka: It looks like it might be gone.

Comment: Found it here: http://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/DemoMonkey/DemoMonkey.zip